# Keep an Arduino Nano and 24 WS2812Bs alive if the power drops for a second

Tags: arduino, power, ws2812b

Im working on a project for a pinball machine, working on a arduino controller and beacon boards to replace old filament flashers,

The supply voltage to the new arduino controller and beacon board will be drop out from time to time for a max of 1 second, this is because the old LEDS would flash.

The project is to replace the old filament lights with the master board and light beacon (both PCB) that is always on regardless if the power drops for a second.

Is there a way that i keep the master and the beacons powered even when the power drops for a second.

the light beacons are 6 WS2812b-minis with their own 100uf capacitors

the master board is 1 arduino nano with 2 dip switches

the light beacons are powered by the master board though IDC cables

Comment: why would the supply voltage drop out due to your LEDs flashing? That sounds like an insufficient power supply, i.e. fix that instead of building around it.

Comment: it was programmed to make the old filament LED flash on for 20 seconds and off for a second

Comment: yeah well, then get a different supply to supply your Arduino... far easier and more sensible to do that than to work with a flashing power supply...

Comment: You might be able to hold up the voltage with caps, but the required capacitance will most likely be huge. What is the nominal operating voltage (5V?)? What is the minimum voltage the circuits will operate at (4.5V?)? How much current do the circuits draw. How much reserve capacity does the power supply have, you will need excess current to recharge the big caps.